# ytdl avoid playing non-public videos

Tags: discord.py, ytdl

I built a discord bot to play the music, it can play also playlist, the problem is that some playlist like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZ_NImYJke0&list=RDDZ_NImYJke0&start_radio=1&ab_channel=Andr%C3%A9Rieu) has about 20 songs visible, but when ytdl download the playlist, there are about 300 songs! they are not private or deleted songs because when they are they appear just like "deleted" or "private", so I wonder why? maybe they are unlisted youtube videos, i don't know, but what if i want to avoid downloading these songs? in the end the user wants to put the playlist and play the songs he sees!

Comment: why are you trying to download why don't you just extract the audio and play the audio it saves time as well as takes no space.

Comment: yeah I set download=False, but anyway to stream the audio, ytdl need data from yt, and during this time, for some playlist, it download also the non-listed video.